# How to export and load Blender 3D mesh with animation to JSON and load it in Three.js r90?

Tags: json, three.js, blender

how to import mesh with animation Blender 3D animation to JSON and load from Three.js 90?
Maybe anybody have how-to? I can't doing this.

```
            loader.load( 'models/fox/fox_run.json', function ( geometry, materials ) {

                // adjust color a bit

                var material = materials[ 0 ];
                material.morphTargets = true;
                material.color.setHex( 0xffaaaa );

                for ( var i = 0; i < 1; i ++ ) {

                    var mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, materials );

                    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                    mesh.updateMatrix();

                    scene.add( mesh );

                    mixer.clipAction( geometry.animations[ 0 ], mesh )
                            .setDuration( 1 )           // one second
                            .startAt( - Math.random() ) // random phase (already running)
                            .play();                    // let's go

                }

            } );
```

[image]

It doesn't play animation...
[image]

After exporting by Three.js r90 exporter I have broken SkinnedMesh. Mesh and Skeleton have offset by Blender configuration, and I have troubles.

[image]

ALRIGHT, GUYS! All I need to do is:
1. Pose Mode select: Pose->Clear Transform->All
2. Object Mode select: Object->Clear Location, Rotation, Scale, Origin.
And My model exports right from Blender to Three.js using JSONLoader!

Answer (score 2):

Is your animation done with armature key frames on each bone? If you are using IK you may need to bake the IK into the action. Google baking blender IK. In the three export settings, make sure you have skinned mesh and animation, and embed animation checked.. if these things don't help, post a codepen or a jsfiddle. Also make sure your animation is set to loop. It may be finishing the animation before you see it for the first time. Hth.

Comment: Thank you! After exporting by Three.js r90 exporter I have broken SkinnedMesh. Mesh and Skeleton have offset by Blender configuration, and I have troubles.